# What new JSON-RPC calls are available with SegWit activation?

Tags: json-rpc, segregated-witness

For example, I can see `getblock` now returns two fields for a block's size:

`size` (all data) and `strippedsize` (base block size, NOT including witness data)

Are there any more RPC updates to interact with witness data? Like return the number of segwit transactions in a block? Or return the `wtxid` or witness data from a specific transaction?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, `strippedsize` was added as a parameter to `getblock()` that shows the block size excluding witness data.

`txinwitness` has been added as value to the response from `getrawtransaction()` and `decoderawtransaction()`.

That's all I was able to pick up from the RPC... I suspect looping through the transactions in each block and checking for the `txinwitness` value could get the number of segwit transactions.